# Comprehensive guide to setting up a data driven website using Amazon web services for EC2

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have started making a website and was hosting on Hostgator but I am going to move it to Amazon web services before launch. There is a small problem that I previously just uploaded my files to the relevant location to Hostgator and it has all just worked. I have no experience in setting up from scratch a production worthy server setup and I need to know how. I did setup the basic lamp stack on the EC2 instance, however, I keep reading that when the EC2 instance does down it will take all the data with it and I can not have that happen. I have also read then when it dies it wont do anything and you have to start up the apache server again it is not automatic. I need it to be reliable and have the data independent so it will not crash, burn and die if the server goes. I have worked out that I will need S3 for static things such as my PDF's and images as well as using the RDS for my MYSQL database. My domain name is registered elsewhere so I believe I need to use route 53 as well.I want to use AWS for a few reasons reasons, firstly as it can scale which is really important but not sure if this is built in or it requires customization. I have been told that it is very secure the EC2 and the last reason is that I can debug my php code. The debug reason is that I have an error that only appears on the Hostgator server not my local lamp stack and I can't debug it there so I should be able to when I move to EC2.

I have done a lot of looking around online and I can't find anything comprehensive about what to setup. I have been reading (some of you may think otherwise). However, I am so overwhelmed by the amount of information there is as it is either far to complicated discussing some theory that I do not care about or to easy and does not discuss how to use anything other then a generic install of a LAMP stack on the EC2 with out using the other services.

I have seen http://bitnami.com/stack/lamp/cloud/amazon but do not think this is what I want as again the EC2 has a mysql database and I am not using the RDS

If someone can point me in the direction of a comprehensive guide to setting up a slid LAMP stack on AWS (mabey even a book has been written) that would be great as I found the amazon docs did not go into much detail and told me how to do things but not why I should do them and what purpose they had.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure a totally unmanaged solution is right for you, from the questions you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

I'll start with answering your q's first, and as you are a newbie I would suggest don't pressurize to learn all of AWS, you can keep migrating slowly and keep discovering the magic of cloud.

> Q. 
>   when the EC2 instance does down it will take all the data with it and
>   I can not have that happen. I have also read then when it dies it wont
>   do anything and you have to start up the apache server again it is not
>   automatic?

A. When an EC2 instance goes down (down could mean shutdown manual by you or Down means AWS network is down, or instances are having some other issues) only the data on "ephemeral data" or you can say data on RAM or sessions will get lost, whatever is on disk will remain on disk, And the instance will be available as soon as problem is resolved.
Apache will start itself when an instance restarts, and remains up until you manually shut it down or some other issue.

> Q. I will need S3 for static things such as my PDF's and images as
>   well as using the RDS for my MYSQL database?

A. Its a good practice to keep static stuff on s3, but not a necessary thing to do, you can set up a ftp or manage your static content like you were used to, like keeping it on a folder of your website.
You don't necessarily need RDS to have a mysql database, I have a process running on aws with around 40 mil transactions a day, and I do it on a normal mysql at an ec2 instance.
however having RDS gets rid from the daily backup and index maintenance hustles.

> Q. My domain name is registered elsewhere so I believe I need to use
>   route 53 as well ?

A. Again not a necessary thing, you can just go to your domain manager and change the A-name or C-name records (with static public ip of ec2) and give a static public ip to your ec2 instance or Elastic load balancer and you'll be up and running in no time.

> Q. I want to use AWS for a few reasons reasons, firstly as it can
>   scale which is really important but not sure if this is built in or it
>   requires customization.

A. It can scale really well, but depends how do you want it to scale, and its highly customizable.
there are 2 kinds of scaling

1. vertical - you change your instance type from one type to another to get better disk / cpu or RAM or better network performance, but this will need you to stop your ec2 instance and change its type, that means there will be downtime of around 10 minutes while you do so.
2. horizontal - you can put your website (ec2 based) behind a load balancer (ELB - elastic load balancer) and add/remove more instances to/from it as and when you deemed suitable, or you can also have an auto scaling policy to help you do it automatically depending up on the load at your web server.

Security? - you can be very well assured its very well secure, and so much secure that I can bet my life on a secure ec2 instance, i can swear by linux thor that it works and it works like a charm.

Debugging? - I suggest you do debugging by classic means, make logs of errors and all, just treat ec2 like a normal machine and learn slowly the tricks of trade.

Now lets setup a basic solid LAMP stack for ourselves, I am assuming that you have a ready ubuntu instance, and you can ssh to it, in case you haven't been able to make one - see [this](http://www.robotmedia.net/2011/04/how-to-create-an-amazon-ec2-instance-with-apache-php-and-mysql-lamp/).

basically.
1. create security groups - This is your firewall, makes sure which ports are open, and also makes sure which ec2 instances can talk amongst themselves.
2. Create an ec2 instance - make any ubuntu instance.
And access your instance using ssh - ssh is basically secure terminal connection to your ec2 machine which is secured by a key file (pem file) and whoever has it can access your machine's data, so keep it very very secure, and you can't afford to lose it.
3. install LAMP using - Tasksel utility
4. setup a public ip for yourself ( costs a dollar per month) - you can use this ip to redirect your www.example.com traffic using domain manager of your DNS provider - godaddy or someone alike i suppose.

I think this will be it to make you start with AWS.

Just to be safe that you have a copy of your data make an AMI of your ec2 instance with all the data on it. AMI is the image from which you can make a similar or better instance in 10 minutes flat (or even lesser).

You wil pay for - instance type you chose, public IP, traffic if its beyond a level (usually very very cheap), and disk usage (8 gb is the default disk), and AMI volume.

Have fun with AWS.

Answer (score 2):

To retain data between during the down time, make sure you use EBS storage. Its default now a days. In the past, before EBS, instance storage was default and you would lose data once server is down, but with the EBS storage, data is retained during the shutdown.

You can go one of the follow two routes depending upon your needs. 
 1. Use AWS ElasticBeanStalk (http://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/)  if you do not need to install anything additional Its super easy and its similar to Google Apps and you can deploy your app quickly. You do not get server, but a server to deploy your app. You have to use RDS for database and S3 for storage. You can not store locally on the server where you are running.

1. Use EC2 server with static IP address. You can get pre-configured LAMP stacks from market place. I use bitnami cloud stacks for AWS that comes pre-configured with LAMP and many other apps. Just use their free account to create micro instance for your PHP and select a server and you are good to go. http://bitnami.com/cloud

You do not need to use Route 53 unless you need to manage DNS programatically. You can just point your server to EC2 server by adding entry in your DNS (godaddy or whoever is your domain name provider).

Bitnami service also allow scheduled backups, but if you are not storing anything locally, you do not need frequent backups.

Make sure you use Multi-AZ option in RDS which is more reliable. When you provision a Multi-AZ DB Instance, Amazon RDS automatically creates a primary DB Instance and synchronously replicates the data to a standby instance in a different Availability Zone (AZ). Also, Amazon RDS automatically patches the database software and backs up your database, storing the backups for a user-defined retention period and enabling point-in-time recovery, up to last 5 minutes.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using dynamo DB (http://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/pricing/) in with LAMP without Mysql for storage. Having a Samebox database can almost never give you reliability. So you will not loose your data what ever your Application box goes through. You can even read our application config from dynamo DB.

1. http://aws.amazon.com/documentation/dynamodb/
2. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/SettingUpTestingSDKPHP.html
3. [Do I need to use EC2 with DynamoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9405339/do-i-need-to-use-ec2-with-dynamodb)

Answer (score 1):

You wont loose data when server is down. Just make sure your select EBS volume, and not Instance.

You can get ready-made server from AWS market place. I used the following for my projects, but there are many other pre-configured servers available.
https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B007IN7GJA/ref=srh_res_product_title?ie=UTF8&sr=0-2&qid=1382655655469

This with RDS server is what you need. We use this all the time for production servers and never had any issues.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few choices:

1. Use only EC2. Install Apache+MySQL and your dynamic website on EC2. This will be very similar to setting it up on Hostgator except you are running a full server.
2. Use EC2 for "compute" (that is, the dynamic part of the site) and S3 for storage. This doesn't differ much from #1 above, except that you are using S3 for static file storage - which is great if you are expecting to host a lot of static content (multimedia, etc)
3. Set up your website using Amazon Elastic Beanstalk (which now supports PHP). However, if you go this route, you will need to host your database somewhere - which will likely be RDS.

I recommend going with #1. There is nothing wrong with that - yes, if EC2 goes down, it will take down your site with it, but to alleviate that, you can run two servers in two different regions (one in US East and one in US West) - I don't think two EC2 regions have ever gone down at the same time.

UPDATE: If you are concerned about backup/restore and making sure your data is safe, I recommend the following (I do this with a site in production on EC2):

- Put your website code into Git/SVN source control; and pull from there
- Backup your MySQL database to Amazon S3 regularly (at least once a day) using mysqldump

Comment: I can't afford to lose my data and not have a copy of it that would could cost me more than just problems

Answer (score 0):

Here are two guides that look good to me:

http://shout.setfive.com/2013/04/05/amazon-aws-ec2-lamp-quickstart-guide-5-steps-in-10-minutes/

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/install-LAMP.html

If learning the Linux command line isn't your thing, you should consider going "up the stack" to a PaaS (Platform As A Service). They are things like Heroku, Google App Engine, and ElasticBeanStalk.

The trade-off between Infrastructure as a Service (IaaS like EC2) and a Platform as a Service (PaaS like Heroku):
- PasS is quicker to get started, less to learn. IaaS requires you to know the entire stack from the start (or hire/rent a sysadmin).
- PasS usually gets more expensive as you get bigger compared to IaaS (but it depends).
- PaaS has less control (you can't choose the language version, so you can't upgrade to get around a specific bug.)
- IaaS can literally do anything (it's just a Linux box)
- IaaS allows for more tuning (upgrade libraries to get features, switch to different instance type to trade off RAM for CPU, run HipHop for speed, add caching layers, etc)

Comment: Those guides do exactly what I don't want to do as if the instance goes down I loose everything. If I loose the database which could contain important information then I would be in a world of trouble

Comment: In that case, find an EBS backed AMI, or use RDS.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have some misconceptions.

If EC2 as a whole goes down (which is rare) then you do NOT lose your data.  The site would simply be offline until Amazon restored services.

If your particular instance goes down due to a hardware issue, then you *might* lose data.  This is no different than if your own server went belly up.  The right answer is to simply make normal backups of your database and store it in S3 or some other location.  Generally you will want to create and attach a second EBS volume to your DB server which has the DB files on it as well.

If you Terminate your instance then, yes you will lose everything on that.  However Amazon has the ability to make terminating instances difficult so you don't do it accidentally.

Stopping your instance is like turning the computer off.  The difference being that you can remotely turn it back on when you want.  You can only stop EBS backed instances - which means that your data is safe while it is offline.

---

I would highly suggest that if you are uncomfortable with setting up and maintaining your own server that you should investigate fully managed hosting instead.  EC2 is awesome, we've been on it for 2 years.  However, we have a strong tech team that understands what it takes to run and manage servers.